# How did he split the bits in the physical address?

Tags: computer-science, comparator, cpu-architecture

I was learning Computer Architecture, and I found a question and an answer that I don't get it.

It says that the L1 Cache is 32Kbyte and 4-way set associative. Then it asks about the comparators (which are Four), how many bits they use. The Physical Address is 32 bits.

The guy answered:

```
Tag = ?

Set Address = 8 bits

Address of Bytes = 5 bits

Tag = 32 - 8 -5 = **19 bits**.
```

What I don't get is, how did he do this splitting of the 32 bits? Why does the **Sett Address** have 8 bits, and why does the **Address of Bytes** have 5 bits?

Answer (score 0):

Whoever solved this, made an implicit assumption (or you missed copying it) that a cacheline is 32 Byte long. By the way, most modern CPUs use 64 Bytes.

This means, that 32kB L1 stores 1024 lines of 32 bytes each, which are organized in 4 ways, making it 256 sets. This means you need 8 bits out of the address to denote the set.

In addition, you need to remove the byte offset within the line - since the line is 32 bytes (again - not given here) - you need 5 bits for that.

This means 8 + 5 bits out of each address are used to map a byte within the cache, leaving 19 bits out of the 32bit address for tag (don't confuse the 32 address size here with the cacheline size, it's orthogonal).

Now, let's assume for a second he was wrong, and the cacheline size is 64 bytes.
In that case you would have half the sets, so only 7 bits for set mapping, but you'd need one additional bit for the offset, leaving exactly the same for tag. This is probably why the author of the question didn't see fit to provide this information.